# TypeError: Object function EventEmitter()

Tags: javascript, node.js, events

I have Node.js EventEmitter error. When i'm running my script i'm getting this error. Script is under backtrace. It's billing object(it must update money value in MongoDB).

```
C:\node\billing\node_modules\models\ticket.js:20
emitter.on('new_bill', function(){
    ^
TypeError: Object function EventEmitter() {
  this.domain = null;
  if (exports.usingDomains) {
    // if there is an active domain, then attach to it.
    domain = domain || require('domain');
    if (domain.active && !(this instanceof domain.Domain)) {
      this.domain = domain.active;
    }
  }
  this._events = this._events || {};
  this._maxListeners = this._maxListeners || defaultMaxListeners;
  } has no method 'on'
  at Object.<anonymous> (C:\node\billing\node_modules\models\ticket.js:20:9)
at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
at require (module.js:380:17)
at Object.<anonymous> (C:\node\billing\node_modules\routes\pay.js:1:76)
at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
DEBUG: Program node app exited with code 8
```

Here's my script:

```
var emitter = require('events').EventEmitter;
var log4js = require('log4js');
var log = log4js.getLogger();
var redis = require("redis"),
   client = redis.createClient();
var HttpError = require('error').HttpError;
var User = require("models/user").User;


function ticket(req, res, next, code, amount){
   this.req = req;
   this.res = res;
   this.next = next;
   this.code = code;
   this.amount = amount;
}

emitter.prototype = ticket;

emitter.on('new_bill', function(){
   client.set(this.code, this.amount);
});


emitter.on('bill_closed', function(){
   client.get(this.code, function (err, amount) {
        if(err) var err = new HttpError(500, "Redis connection failed");
        log.error(err);
        this.next(err);
        User.upMoney(this.req.session.user._id, amount, function(err){
            if(err) var err = new HttpError(500, "Redis connection failed");
            log.error(err);
            this.next(err);
        });
    });
 });


exports.module = emitter;
```

Here, i am using node js with v0.10.25. 
I didn't find any way to solve this issue in Google. 
Can anyone help to solve this issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `EventEmitter` is supposed to be instantiated with `new`.

```
var Emitter = require('events').EventEmitter,
    emitter = new Emitter();
```

http://nodejs.org/api/events.html

Comment: This information isn't found in older docs: https://nodejs.org/dist/v0.10.36/docs/api/events.html

Answer (score 0):

You are not creating your object the right way.
You should use inheritance:

```
var EventEmitter = require('events').EventEmitter;
var util = require('util');

function Ticket(req, res, next, code, amount){
  EventEmitter.call(this);
  this.req = req;
  this.res = res;
  this.next = next;
  this.code = code;
  this.amount = amount;
}

util.inherits(Ticket, EventEmitter);

var ticket = module.exports = new Ticket();

ticket.on('new_bill', function () { /* ... */ });
ticket.on('bill_closed', function () { /* ... */ });
```